# Can not enable Plugin in Vernemq

Tags: plugins, erlang

I am getting this error while enabling plugin in vernemq

```
RPC to 'dev1@127.0.0.1' failed: {'EXIT',
                             {{{badmatch,
                                {error,
                                 {http_to_mqtt,
                                  {{shutdown,
                                    {failed_to_start_child,
                                     http_to_mqtt_web,
                                     {'EXIT',
                                      {{case_clause,
                                        {error,
                                         {undef,
                                          [{httpd_util,rfc1123_date,[],[]},
                                           {mochiweb_clock,handle_info,2,
                                            [{file,
                                              "src/mochiweb_clock.erl"},
                                             {line,88}]},
                                           {mochiweb_clock,init,1,
                                            [{file,
                                              "src/mochiweb_clock.erl"},
                                             {line,69}]},
                                           {gen_server,init_it,6,
                                            [{file,"gen_server.erl"},
                                             {line,306}]},
                                           {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                            [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},
                                             {line,237}]}]}}},
                                       [{mochiweb_http,ensure_started,1,
                                         [{file,"src/mochiweb_http.erl"},
                                          {line,76}]},
                                        {mochiweb_http,start,1,
                                         [{file,"src/mochiweb_http.erl"},
                                          {line,68}]},
                                        {supervisor,do_start_child,2,
                                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},
                                          {line,314}]},
                                        {supervisor,start_children,3,
                                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},
                                          {line,297}]},
                                        {supervisor,init_children,2,
                                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},
                                          {line,263}]},
                                        {gen_server,init_it,6,
                                         [{file,"gen_server.erl"},
                                          {line,306}]},
                                        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                         [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},
                                          {line,237}]}]}}}},
                                   {http_to_mqtt_app,start,
                                    [normal,[]]}}}}},
                               [{vmq_plugin_mgr,start_plugin,1,
                                 [{file,
                                   "/Users/sunnyjain/Desktop/vernemq/_build/default/lib/vmq_plugin/src/vmq_plugin_mgr.erl"},
                                  {line,489}]},
                                {vmq_plugin_mgr,start_plugins,1,
                                 [{file,
                                   "/Users/sunnyjain/Desktop/vernemq/_build/default/lib/vmq_plugin/src/vmq_plugin_mgr.erl"},
                                  {line,471}]},
                                {vmq_plugin_mgr,load_plugins,2,
                                 [{file,
                                   "/Users/sunnyjain/Desktop/vernemq/_build/default/lib/vmq_plugin/src/vmq_plugin_mgr.erl"},
                                  {line,410}]},
                                {vmq_plugin_mgr,update_plugins,2,
                                 [{file,
                                   "/Users/sunnyjain/Desktop/vernemq/_build/default/lib/vmq_plugin/src/vmq_plugin_mgr.erl"},
                                  {line,354}]},
                                {vmq_plugin_mgr,handle_plugin_call,2,
                                 [{file,
                                   "/Users/sunnyjain/Desktop/vernemq/_build/default/lib/vmq_plugin/src/vmq_plugin_mgr.erl"},
                                  {line,183}]},
                                {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,
                                 [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,607}]},
                                {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                                 [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,639}]},
                                {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                 [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]},
                              {gen_server,call,
                               [vmq_plugin_mgr,
                                {enable_plugin,http_to_mqtt,
                                 [{paths,
                                   ["/Users/sunnyjain/Desktop/practice/http_to_mqtt"]}]},
                                infinity]}}}
```

The command I am using to enable plugin is:

```
vmq-admin plugin enable -n http_to_mqtt -p /Users/sunnyjain/Desktop/http_to_mqtt
```

If my PATH variable consist the below path then I am not getting the above error

```
/Users/sunnyjain/Desktop/vernemq/_build/default/rel/vernemq/bin
```

but when I change path to

```
/Users/sunnyjain/Desktop/vernemq/_build/dev1/rel/vernemq/bin
```

then I m getting the error. Can someone tell me why the error is coming and how the enabling plugin from "default" node is different from enabling it from "dev1" node. How is plugin dependent on the nodes.

Comment: The root cause (roughly in the middle of the error message) is that mochiweb can't call a function in the `httpd_util` module, which is in the `inets` application. My guess is that the `default` release includes the `inets` application while `dev1` doesn't, or is missing the beam file for some reason.

Comment: Yes your guess is right. I have to enable the inets application as a plugin in vernemq. And now it is working. Thanks for the pointing it out.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer to your own question, so that anyone who gets the same error in the future can easily find how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error was coming because the inets application is not started.

To enable the inets in vernemq you can type the following commands

```
vmq-admin plugin enable -n inets --path /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/inets-5.10.6
```

This will remove the error.

Comment: If you require 'inets' to be started in your plugin, you should add it to the 'application' section in the .app.src file of your plugin.  If you're doing this, then the "vmq-admin plugin enable -n 'yourplugin'.." will automatically start 'inets' prior starting your plugin.

Comment: @Andre It says {inets,{"no such file or directory","inets.app"}} . Do we have to give the path to inets.app in application section? If yes then what is the format to write it?

Comment: the inets application isn't packaged as part of the Erlang release. I'd recommend to change to add the inets application to the relx configuration and rebuild the release.

I don't recommend to use `vmq-admin plugin enable` to start other applications than VerneMQ plugins.